# ViteJS unable to compile jsx sourcemaps within packaged node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vite

I setup a new configuration for vite_rails and some of the npm packages cannot be parsed due to them using jsx.map extensions. I tried a handful of techniques that I came across. But I'm not sure why my config doesn't auto parse jsx in the node_modules folder, but does it for every other part of the js ecosystem. **How can I fix my configuration to handle jsx in the node_modules folder for vitejs-rails edition?**

**Error**

```
Unexpected: ";" in source map
//# sourceMappingURL=Post.jsx.map
```

**ViteJS Config**

```
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite'
import ViteRails from 'vite-plugin-rails'
import sass from 'sass'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: 'inline',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {},
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        implementation: sass,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'jsx-to-js-converter',
      async transform(code, id) {
        if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/)) return null
        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: 'jsx',
          jsx: 'automatic',
        })
      },
    },
    react(),
    ViteRails({
      fullReload: {
        additionalPaths: ['app/javascript/**/*', 'app/frontend/entrypoints/**/*'],
      },
    }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {

    },
  },
})
```